# Browser XSS: am I missing something?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cross-domain

I feel like I am missing something fundamental about XSS prevention (either in general or about the browsers' current implementation of it).

I have a site at domain A, that uses jQuery.  Under certain conditions I want it to periodically retrieve and format some data which is hosted at domain B.

In the source for domain A's page, it appears that I can quite happily put in a `<script src="http://B/something.js"></script>` and it will load and execute the script in the context of the current page (in particular allowing it to read and update the DOM).  I can also do the same thing using `jQuery.getScript` (which internally fetches and executes the script via AJAX).

However regardless of whether I put it into the domain A page or into the JS on domain B, if I try to use `jQuery.ajax` to load `http://B/data.json` it generates a CORS violation error:

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

(Note that while testing this, domain A is a local `file://`, which is probably why it's showing a null origin there.  It will be a "real" site in practice.)

I am having a hard time understanding this behaviour.  I fail to see how loading JSON data is in any way less safe than loading arbitrary script -- in fact the opposite seems more likely.

Mostly I'm asking this question to try to understand how this can possibly make sense, but as a side question I'm interested to know the "right" way to perform this sort of thing (have a script on domain B be able to load data from its own domain, despite being run from domain A).  It *is* possible for me to add the Allow-Origin header to domain B if absolutely required, but I would prefer not to do so.  (It's not possible to do this on domain A.)

Comment: In particular one of the things that puzzles me is why SOP/CORS blocks requests by `http://B/something.js` to access `http://B/data.json`.  Isn't that the same origin at that point?

Comment: The origin is defined by the page, not where the code was loaded from.

Comment: I suppose that's convenient for loading externally-hosted JS libraries (such as jQuery itself), but it still seems counter-intuitive to me.  Shouldn't code stored on domain B be trusted by data providers on domain B?  (Though I guess the reason this isn't done is that it'd require individually tracking the origin of each function and closure in all the weird ways that JS lets you store them, which would be a lot of work.  On the other hand, the JS debugging tools that are built into most browsers now basically have to do that anyway.)